# (Processing) Removing Previously Used Object in Array

Tags: arrays, arraylist, processing

Sorry for the horrible wording of the title. I'm creating a game of "War" in Processing for my Programming class. I need to change my code so that each card that is used is removed from the deck/array. I stumbled upon some posts and Google results mentioning "ArrayList", but I'm still sort of clueless.

The following code displays two separate, random cards and displays two new random cards when the mouse is clicked.

**(First Tab 'War')**

```
void draw(){
image(card[imageIndex],40,150);
image(card2[imageIndex2],340,150);
}

void mousePressed(){
imageIndex = int(random(card.length));
imageIndex2 = int(random(card2.length));
}
```

**(Second Tab 'Card')**

```
PImage[] card = new PImage[13];
PImage[] card2 = new PImage[13];
int imageIndex = int(random(0,12)),
imageIndex2 = int(random(0,12));

void setup(){
size(500,500);
card[0] = loadImage("2_of_clubs.jpg");
card[1] = loadImage("3_of_clubs.jpg");
card[2] = loadImage("4_of_clubs.jpg");
card[3] = loadImage("5_of_clubs.jpg");
card[4] = loadImage("6_of_clubs.jpg");
card[5] = loadImage("7_of_clubs.jpg");
card[6] = loadImage("8_of_clubs.jpg");
card[7] = loadImage("9_of_clubs.jpg");
card[8] = loadImage("10_of_clubs.jpg");
card[9] = loadImage("jack_of_clubs.jpg");
card[10] = loadImage("queen_of_clubs.jpg");
card[11] = loadImage("king_of_clubs.jpg");
card[12] = loadImage("ace_of_clubs.jpg");

card2[0] = loadImage("2_of_clubs.jpg");
card2[1] = loadImage("3_of_clubs.jpg");
card2[2] = loadImage("4_of_clubs.jpg");
card2[3] = loadImage("5_of_clubs.jpg");
card2[4] = loadImage("6_of_clubs.jpg");
card2[5] = loadImage("7_of_clubs.jpg");
card2[6] = loadImage("8_of_clubs.jpg");
card2[7] = loadImage("9_of_clubs.jpg");
card2[8] = loadImage("10_of_clubs.jpg");
card2[9] = loadImage("jack_of_clubs.jpg");
card2[10] = loadImage("queen_of_clubs.jpg");
card2[11] = loadImage("king_of_clubs.jpg");
card2[12] = loadImage("ace_of_clubs.jpg");
}
```

Comment: perhaps this article can be of help. It has been moved and I could only find this not formmated version. Anyway worth reading ;)  http://archive-org.com/page/4420950/2014-08-17/http://wiki.processing.org/index.php?title=Why_use_ArrayList_instead_of_array_with_append%28%29%3F&action=edit

Comment: Yeah, you should probably use an ArrayList for this. What happened when you googled "ArrayList tutorial"? You could use an array and just set the index you want to remove to null as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using ArrayList would look more or less like:

```java
// gonna use strings instead of images
// just to show the idea. I don't have all this images...
ArrayList<String> card = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> card2;

int imageIndex, imageIndex2;

String display1, display2;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  card.add("2_of_clubs.jpg");
  card.add("3_of_clubs.jpg");
  card.add("4_of_clubs.jpg");
  card.add("5_of_clubs.jpg");
  card.add("6_of_clubs.jpg");
  card.add("7_of_clubs.jpg");
  card.add("8_of_clubs.jpg");
  card.add("9_of_clubs.jpg");
  card.add("10_of_clubs.jpg");
  card.add("jack_of_clubs.jpg");
  card.add("queen_of_clubs.jpg");
  card.add("king_of_clubs.jpg");
  card.add("ace_of_clubs.jpg");

  card2 = new ArrayList<String>(card);


  imageIndex = int(random(card.size()));
  imageIndex2 = int(random(card2.size()));

  display1 = card.get(imageIndex);
  display2 = card2.get(imageIndex2);

  card.remove(imageIndex);
  card2.remove(imageIndex2);

  println("\ncard draw from card : "+ display1);
  println("card draw from card2: "+ display2 + "\n");
}

void draw() {
}

void mousePressed() {
  if (card.size() > 0) {
    imageIndex = int(random(card.size()));
    imageIndex2 = int(random(card2.size()));

    display1 = card.get(imageIndex);
    display2 = card2.get(imageIndex2);

    card.remove(imageIndex);
    card2.remove(imageIndex2);

    println("\ncard draw from card : "+ display1);
    println("card draw from card2: "+ display2 + "\n");
  } else {
    println("The deck is empty...");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have to use arrays then you would have to do something similar to the following code:

```
PImage[] removeCardFromDeck(PImage deck, int index){
  PImage[] newdeck = new PImage[deck.length -1];
  int count=0;
  for(int i =0 ; i<newdeck.length;i++){
    if(count==index) count++;
    newdeck[i] = deck[count];
    count++;    
  }
  return newdeck;
}
```

but for this task it is better to use ArrayLists.